# Differ controller RedirectToAction on a caller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 Views from which I can call function from the controler:

- Index
- MyDevices

Is there any way  RedirectToAction will redirect to Index or MyDevices depends of a caller without coping the code under new name with only change in RedirectToAction("parameter")?

Below You can see my controller method

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="DeviceId,DeviceSerialNumber,DeviceUser,DeviceDictionaryId,Batch,Start,End")] Device device)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(device);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your views, within your form, add a hidden field named `viewName` holding the name of the current view. In your controller make these changes (add the `viewName` parameter and redirect according to its value):

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="DeviceId,DeviceSerialNumber,DeviceUser,DeviceDictionaryId,Batch,Start,End")] Device device, string viewName)
{
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          db.Entry(device).State = EntityState.Modified;
          db.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction(viewName);
     }
     return View(device);
}
```